# Invoking "-j8 -l8" failed

Tags: ros, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to install the tim_sumulator and I followed this guide for ros indigo https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator.
Instead of creating a new workspace I downloaded the dependencies in my catkin_src/src directory. Now when I try to "catkin_make" while in the "catkin_ws" directory, I get this error Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

The following is what I get from the terminal:

Base path: /home/jtu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jtu/catkin_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/jtu/catkin_ws/build"

[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawImu
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AttitudeCommand
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RuddersCommand
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeightCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawRC
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PositionXYCommand
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ServoCommand
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorCommand
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Supply
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ControllerState
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ThrustCommand
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_HeadingCommand
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Altimeter
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelocityZCommand
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorPWM
[  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelocityXYCommand
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Altitude
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_YawrateCommand
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MotorStatus
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Compass
Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RC
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RawMagnetic
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_of
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_RecordEnable
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_raw_measures
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_kalman_pressure
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pwm
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_video_stream
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_time
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_detect
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_euler_angles
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_Navdata
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_altitude
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_CamSelect
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_rc_references
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_trackers_send
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector31
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_FlightAnim
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix33
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_hdvideo_stream
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_references
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_demo
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_perf
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_trims
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_vision_raw
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_watchdog
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wifi
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_games
Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_adc_data_frame
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_zimmu_3000
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_phys_measures
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_magneto
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_wind_speed
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_gyros_offsets
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_vector21
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_LedAnim
[  0%] Built target _ardrone_autonomy_generate_messages_check_deps_navdata_pressure_raw
Performing update step for 'ardronelib'
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _eagle_one_test_generate_messages_check_deps_Pid_receive
[  0%] Built target _eagle_one_test_generate_messages_check_deps_Pid2
[  0%] [  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
Performing configure step for 'ardronelib'
[  0%] Built target _eagle_one_test_generate_messages_check_deps_Test
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] No configure
Built target _eagle_one_test_generate_messages_check_deps_State
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _eagle_one_test_generate_messages_check_deps_Pid_send
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins_generate_messages_check_deps_SetBias
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Performing build step for 'ardronelib'
Building CXX object tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp.o
Building CXX object tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp.o
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule. Building CXX object tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp.o Building CXX object tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o [  0%] [  0%] Built target test_trajectory Building CXX object tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/reset_plugin.dir/src/reset_plugin.cpp.o In file included from /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp:29:0: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_gps.h:32:28: fatal error: common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory #include "common/Plugin.hh" ^ compilation terminated. In file included from /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp:29:0: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_sonar.h:32:28: fatal error: common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory #include "common/Plugin.hh" ^ compilation terminated. In file included from /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp:29:0: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_magnetic.h:32:28: fatal error: common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory #include "common/Plugin.hh" ^ compilation terminated. Libs already extracted Building target static In file included from /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/reset_plugin.cpp:29:0: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/reset_plugin.h:32:28: fatal error: common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory #include "common/Plugin.hh" ^ compilation terminated. [  1%] Built target message_to_tf In file included from /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp:36:0: /home/jtu/catkin_ws/src/tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/include/hector_gazebo_plugins/diffdrive_plugin_6w.h:30:28: fatal error: common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory #include "common/Plugin.hh" ^ compilation terminated. [  2%] make[2]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/src/gazebo_ros_gps.cpp.o] Error 1 Built target tum_ardrone_gencfg make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_gps.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... make[2]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/src/gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/src/gazebo_ros_magnetic.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/hector_gazebo_ros_magnetic.dir/all] Error 2 [  5%] Built target thirdparty make[2]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/reset_plugin.dir/src/reset_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/reset_plugin.dir/all] Error 2 Architecture x86_64 is already built Creating universal static lib file from architectures x86_64 Build done. Checking required Ubuntu packages ... make[2]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/src/diffdrive_plugin_6w.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [tum_simulator/cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins/CMakeFiles/diffdrive_plugin_6w.dir/all] Error 2 ok. Building ARDroneTool/Lib Building ARDroneTool/Lib [  5%] Performing install step for 'ardronelib' make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add` +' to parent make rule.
[  5%] Completed 'ardronelib'
[  7%] Built target ardronelib
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

---

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258033/invoking-%22-j8--l8%22-failed/) by [SupermanPrime01](https://answers.ros.org/users/29845/supermanprime01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"No such file or directory #include "common/Plugin.hh" " compilation terminated is the cause of your problems.

Looks like you need to download the gazebo source

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0